# Inline "required" asterisk in Laravel form label

Tags: php, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to add a red asterisk for my required fields in Laravel, but I'm not sure how to add them inline with the label.

What I'm doing currently is

```
{{ Form::label('took_act_or_sat' , 'Did you or will you take the SAT or ACT?' ) }} <span style="color: red">*</span>
```

but when the label wraps to a second line, for some reason the asterisk is being bumped an extra line down.

[image: asterisk]

So I guess the first part of my question is: Can you add inline styling to a form label in Laravel?

And the second part is: Is there another way I should be going about adding the asterisk (or other marker) so that this wouldn't be an issue?

If it's relevant, I'm also using Bootstrap for the majority of my styling if that also affects anything.

Comment: Side note: You don't *have* to use `blade` templating or Laravel's `Form` helper. It works great for a lot of inputs, but if you need more control, you can always use `<label></label>` aka basic HTML.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a class to your label with the third parameter

```
{{ Form::label('took_act_or_sat' , 'Did you or will you take the SAT or ACT?', array('class' => 'required') ) }}
```

And add asterisk with css

```
<style>
    .required:after{ 
        content:'*'; 
        color:red; 
        padding-left:5px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ Form::label('took_act_or_sat' , 'Did you or will you take the SAT or ACT? <span style="color: red">*</span>','',false ) }}
```

All you need is **false** as parameter.

Comment: not sure why this is not the accepted answer as it seems to be a better option in order to add some inline content.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. if you want to achieve required result without changing your HTML code then you can add some style to your span elemnt as follows

**Code**

```
{{ Form::label('took_act_or_sat' , 'Did you or will you take the SAT or ACT?' ) }} <span style="color: red; display:block; float:right">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<label for="took_act_or_sat">Did you or will you take the SAT or ACT? <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
```