# How to write html tag inside blade form object label..?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to write "Name * : ", where astrix will be red.
i am creating label as:

```
    {!! Form::label("name","Name".<span class="red">*</span>." :") !!}
```

But this will result in:Name with html tag span tag.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804668/inline-required-asterisk-in-laravel-form-label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you have to pass an `array`. Something like below:

```
{!! Form::label("name", "Name:", array('class' => 'require') !!}
```

And style this `require` class below way. Hope this should work.

```
.require:after{ 
    content:'*'; 
    color:red; 
}
```

**Another way, UPDATED:**

I think, this one you looking for. Use double quotes in `span` and inner `style` use single quotes.

```
{!! Form::label('name', 'Name:'),"<span style='color:red'>*</span>" !!}
```

This should work.

Comment: @gaurav see this updated answer.This is you looking for.Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

```
label.required:after {
  color: red;
  content: "* :";
}

 {!! Form::label("name","Name", array('class' => 'required')) !!}
```

Comment: But this will make colon in red also, i just want * in red

Answer (score 2):

Use an `array` as third argument:

```
{!! Form::label("name", "Name", array('class' => 'redast')) !!}
```

And CSS will be:

```
.redast{
    color: #000000;
}    

.redast:after{
    color: #FF0000;
    content: '*'; 
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Also, why not using something like this:

```
<div>
    <span>{!! Form::label("name", "Name") !!}</span>
    <span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span>
    <span>&nbsp;:</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i have to write * also with red in color, your code will make "Name" in red.

Comment: Like this one: Name * :
where * will be red

Comment: Please try my updated code and let me know if it works or not for you.

Comment: your code work fine, but i need ":" after * . which is black in color.

Comment: Check the alternative with spans please, it should definitely work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the a css style to add the astrix or also, you can create you own macro to display whatever you need:

```
Form::macro('myCustomLabel', function($inputName){

    return "<label for='$inputName'>Name<span class="red">*</span></label>";
});
```

Check this link, is very helpfull: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/173/creating-form-macros

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any commas just append the span after name or label like this.

```
   {!! Form::label("name","Name <span class='red'>*</span> :") !!}
```